# jQuery form submit event handler doesn't get called (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying to make a simple chrome extension which opens a url in a new tab.
The problem is, I can't seem to figure out why my function (the one in popup.js) is not run when I submit the form (by pressing enter).

Here's my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Chromerator",
  "description": "Vim-like functionality added to chrome",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
      "tabs"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-2.1.1.min.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                min-width: 300px;
                max-width: 300px;
            } 

            #q {
               width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <form class="f">
            <input type="text" id="q" autofocus></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
$('.f').submit(function ( event ) {
    var url = "http://" + &('#q').val();
    chrome.tabs.create({ 'url': url });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues here:

1) You have a typo in your code.

```
&('#q').val();
```

should be

```
$('#q').val();
```

2) As @Magnus Engdal has mentioned, you need to wrap your event handler after dom ready:

```
$(function() {
    $('.f').submit(function ( event ) {
        var url = "http://" + $('#q').val();
        chrome.tabs.create({ 'url': url });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

3) Content Scripts doesn't run in the context of an extension.  You need to include jquery in your popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                min-width: 300px;
                max-width: 300px;
            } 

            #q {
               width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
        <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <form class="f">
            <input type="text" id="q" autofocus></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

gl.

Comment: It works, hurray! Although there is something weird still. It works when ran as an extension, but when i open popup.html in chrome, it doesn't. Why could that be? Is it about permissions?

Comment: check the error console.  Most likely it is throwing an error at chrome.tabs.create({ 'url': url }); since the chrome object is only defined when loaded as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

If that's all there is in popup.js, then you need to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() {});` or `$(function() {});`.

```
$(function() {
    $('.f').submit(function ( event ) {
        var url = "http://" + &('#q').val();
        chrome.tabs.create({ 'url': url });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it still does not work for me for whatever reason, any guesses what could cause that? BTW that was all there was in popup.js

Comment: Hard to say without more information. Could you try to replicate your problem on JSFiddle, something like this http://jsfiddle.net/2hjwr0rs/.

Comment: It does work on JSFiddle. There is a difference there however. You included a button on there, whereas in my .html file there is none. Is a button mandatory? That would be silly wouldn't it?

Comment: It's not mandatory, so that's not the problem (no idea why I decided to add a button). Have you placed a breakpoint inside the function to se if it runs at all? Are there any errors thrown in the console?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by a breakpoint (quite new to js), but I have tried alert('whatever'); instead of making it open a url, and it did not work either, indicating that the handler is not ran at all. Could the problem be not setting a permission in manifest.json?

Comment: Could be, but that's beyond my knowledge so then I don't think I can help any further :(

Comment: If i put alert('whatever'); and i run popup.html simply in chrome (no extension), the alert pops up.